# Input fields not registering focus event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am confused as to why this is not doing anything (no errors):

```
<div id="vehicle_form">
<input class="dField" type="email" name="email" value="Email"><br/>
<input class="dField" type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name"><br/>
<input class="dField" type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name"><br/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>


$('.dField').focusin(function(){
    console.log('focus');
});
```

Comment: works for me too have alook here http://jsfiddle.net/MecUs/4/

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (v1.6.2):

```
$('.dField').focusin(function(){
    alert('focus');
})
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: While it's noble of SO to flag "low quality" questions, I think it's ridiculous to expect people to go back and edit things that are over a year old. I have THOUSANDS of answers here, some of them made in haste, I don't see how this comment benefits anyone.

Comment: I see what you say, this answer just popped up to me on review.

Answer (score -1):

```
   $(".dField").focusin(function(){
    console.log('focus');
    });
```

Working Example:   http://api.jquery.com/focusin/

Jquery Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/focusin/